# PHP "Simple" query takes massive time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a question about performance, I guess that I am doing something wrong.

I have one table with Items, and another one with Categories, any item can be in multiple categories. Now I want to show all Items with are not included in any category.

Connections are in table `Items_Categories` (just with `ID_item` and `ID_category`)

I made this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Items AS i
WHERE ID_item NOT
IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID_item
    FROM Items_Categories
)
```

It works, but it's very slow. It takes a few seconds, and my DB is not so big. I have about 3000 Items and maybe 200 categories.

Any better solutions?

Comment: Do you need to select everything? If not only select the columns you need, this will speed up the query

Comment: Start by telling us what indexes you have on these tables, and what the result of an EXPLAIN on the query shows

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use a JOIN instead and find the ones that don't have any matching.

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN Items_Categories ic
    ON i.ID_item = ic.ID_Item
WHERE
    ic.ID_Item IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM Items AS i 
LEFT JOIN Items_Categories  IC on IC.ID_item = I.ID_item
where IC.ID_item is null
```

Comment: This will return items with categories too, it will return those items that haven't got all categories.

Answer (score 0):

You could take this approach and check the execution plan of yours and mine with EXPLAIN, as Mark Baker recommended:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Items i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Items_Categories WHERE ID_item = i.ID_item
);
```

You should have indexed the ID_item column in both tables of course.